# highlighting for text field with docValues="true" doesn't work in solr

Tags: solr, highlight

I am using Solr 8.0.
To be able to use **docValues="true"** with **class="solr.TextField"** , I installed [solr-dvtf](https://github.com/grossws/solr-dvtf/releases).
Here is the **text_hl** field setting in shema.xml:

```
    <fieldType name="text_general_dvtf" class="org.anenerbe.solr.DocValuesTextField" indexed="false" stored="false" multiValued="true" docValues="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="/var/solr/data/core4/conf/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="/var/solr/data/core4/conf/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <copyField source="text" dest="text_hl" />
```

Now I want to implement highlighting for this field, but I get an empty result for highlighting. I want to understand what needs to be done to make the highlight for this field work, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: is your field marked as stored=true? It needs to be

Comment: Please share the query fired to solr..would be helpful

Comment: Yes you are right. When I set stored=true the text_hl field was highlighted. But the results are not what I expected. When I have <str name="f.text_hl.hl.snippets">200</str> in my solrconfig.xml, exactly 200 lines are displayed as a result in highlighting for text_hl. It does not matter how many query values were found.

Comment: here is my request: localhost:8983/solr/core6/select?defType=edismax&hl.fl=title%2C%20text_hl%2C%20text&hl.highlightMultiTerm=false&hl.requireFieldMatch=false&hl.usePhraseHighLighter=false&hl=true&indent=true&q.op=OR&q=man&qf=title%5E10%20text_hl%5E1%20text%5E1&rows=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `stored=true` for your field in order to achieve the highlighting.

Add the attribute to your field in the `schema.xml` and restart the server and re-index the data.

Comment: Thank you Abhijit Bashetti. Yes, it worked. But the selection is wrong. When I have <str name="f.text_hl.hl.snippets">200</str> in my solrconfig.xml, the selection for text_hl shows exactly 200 lines. It doesn't matter how many query values were found. For example, I search for "dinosaur", 3 words were found for the document. But instead of showing 3 fragments with the word "dinosaur" exactly 200 lines are shown. And only the first 3 lines contain the word "dinosaur". How can this be fixed? So that only found results are highlighted?

Comment: This is how the sole works...it gets the fragment of 200 where your query word appears...but is you primary question resolved? if yes, please accept the answer and ask another question...